# How do I change the output format of a print statement in python?

Tags: python, string

I wrote a code like below

```
A = print("apple")
```

And, 
I want to change the data type of A to string, so I wrote the following code.

```
A = str(print"apple")
type(A)
```

But, the answer was "None". In this 
What should I do in this situation?

Actually what I'm doing right now is to write something like the output to a text file.

```
openFp = open("solution.txt","w")
p2 = str(print("I_B : ",I_B))
openFp.writelines(p2+"\n")
openFp.close()
```

Entering this code will always result in 'None'.

Comment: `Print` function does not return values, Instead it write the value into the `stdout`(by default). Why don't you store the string directly into a variable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I think you have misunderstood the function of `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's impossible.

Because `print` just simply prints the parameter, then returns nothing, so you force to print the `print(...)` or make as variable it's gonna be None, so nothing you can do.